# Spliting a single record into multiple records using MySQL triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I want to create a before or after insert trigger in MySQL that splits a record into multiple records based on a special char delimited value.

A record is added to my table like this:

```
INSERT INTO person (id, name, number)
VALUES (3, John, 2|5|6);
```

The insert trigger should get the `number` field and split the values based on the `|` char.
Then it should create three new records:

```
INSERT INTO person (id, name, number)
VALUES (3, John, 2);
INSERT INTO person (id, name, number)
VALUES (4, John, 5);
INSERT INTO person (id, name, number)
VALUES (5, John, 6);
```

Then the initial record is deleted.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have a delimited list in the first place?

Comment: It's the output of a third party form. Can't change it.

Comment: There's a form whose output is a row in a database table? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes. Records are added to a table in a similar way as the example. I can't change this part. I have to split the record that is added into multiple records. I'm asking if and how it can be done with before or after triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could stick something like this inside a trigger...

Data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bad_table;

CREATE TABLE bad_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,number VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO bad_table VALUES
(3, "John", "2|5|6");
```

Query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (n) AS
(
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM cte WHERE n <= 
  (SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(number)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(number,'|','')) FROM bad_table)
)
SELECT id+n-1 id
     , name
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(number,'|',n),'|',-1)x 
  FROM cte
  JOIN bad_table;

+------+------+------+
| id   | name | x    |
+------+------+------+
|    3 | John | 2    |
|    4 | John | 5    |
|    5 | John | 6    |
+------+------+------+
```